# iOS 8 Game with SpriteKit for any device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, size-classes

I'm creating a very simple game using `Sprite Kit` in `Swift`. The game has a simple grid of `SpriteKitNodes` and I would like to ask what's the better way to develop it for all devices in a single shot.

I've learned the new `Size Classes` feature in the Storyboard but could it be used here in with `SpriteKit`? How could I implement the constraint via code?

Here I'm simply creating the nodes in determined positions but of course they needs to be manipulated depending of the size of the device.

```
func addNodeToScene(x: CGPoint,y: CGPoint)
    {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(color: self.colorOfSpriteNode, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

        node = String(format: "node%d", self.nodeIdentifier)
        ++self.nodeIdentifier

        node.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        addChild(node)
    }
```

I've checked the class [SKContraint](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/distance:toNode:), could it be used for this purpose?